# Android App "Stops Working" after Splash Screen

Tags: java, android

My Application stops working after the Splash Screen - keep in mind that this is the very first Android App I have ever developed. Help would be greatly appreciated.

**SplashScreen.java:**

```
package tomperry.goodlife;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
    Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

**AndroidManifist.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tomperry.goodlife">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"
></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>

                <action android:name="tomperry.goodlife.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: this may help you: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/

Answer (score 1):

Your `Intent` is empty. You did not tell where to go. Replace it on your `finally` block -

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, NextActivity.class); //Change "NextActivity" as your need 
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given reference to main activity.

try this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove intent filter from Main Activity in Manifest file

```
<intent-filter>

                <action android:name="tomperry.goodlife.MAINACTIVITY" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the destination where to go. In finally block your Intent is empty. So change this code line into finally block:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
```

to

```
Intent intent = new Intent( SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43320557/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your `finally` block with this:

`startActivity(new Intent(Splashscreen.this,MainActivity.class));`